# Is it a bad practice to cache user's hashed credentials on the server

Tags: security, caching, credentials

I have an application where I read the user object quite frequently in the app. I am planning to cache user object which also has his hashed credentials(hashed). Client has access to port HTTPS port 443 only. In what scenario can an attacker/another process potentially get access to my cache.

Is this a bad practice - why or in what cases.

Comment: I think, its nothing wrong to store hash password in cache. because hasing is a irreversible process. so you are not in danger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on where you're caching it.

If you're caching it in memcached, where any process on the network can access it (there's no authentication at all), then yes, that is a problem.

If you're caching it in memory on machine (a shared memory blob, etc), then it's fine (since the OS controls will guard the memory segment from other users).

If you're caching it using something like Redis with authentication turned on, then you're fine.

In short, if your cache is authenticated, then go for it. If it's not (and is open for any arbitrary user on the network to read) then definitely do not.